# SQL Server - storing SELECT statement into a variable in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Stored Procedure, I am trying to store the result of a SELECT statement inside a variable. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @process_pk uniqueidentifier
INSERT INTO @process_pk
    SELECT process_pk 
    FROM dbo.Process 
    WHERE process_id = @process_id
```

In the above, I'm trying to *store the result of the SELECT statement into my variable @process_pk*, to be used sometime later in the latter part of my stored procedure. But it doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.

> I would like to ask what is the correct way to store SELECT statement
>   results inside a Stored Procedure variable so that it can be used
>   anytime within the stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SET @process_PK = (SELECT process_pk 
    FROM dbo.Process 
    WHERE process_id = @process_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @process_pk = process_pk 
FROM dbo.Process 
WHERE process_id = @process_id;
```

This is particularly handy if you want to set multiple values from the same query:

```
SELECT @process_pk = p.process_pk,
       @col1 = p.col1 
FROM dbo.Process p 
WHERE p.process_id = @process_id;
```